# RegisterClassEx in .NET fails

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, unmanaged

I am registering a class via RegisterClassEx, but after this step the window does not appear anymore.

Here is how I register it:

```
        wcx = new WNDCLASSEX();
        wcx.cbSize = Convert.ToUInt32(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WNDCLASSEX)));          // size of structure 
        wcx.style = ClassStyles.HorizontalRedraw | ClassStyles.VerticalRedraw; // redraw if size changes 
        wcx.lpfnWndProc = ProcessWndProc;     // points to window procedure 
        wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;                // no extra class memory 
        wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;                // no extra window memory 
        wcx.hInstance = hinstance;         // handle to instance 
        wcx.hIcon = IntPtr.Zero;              // predefined app. icon 
        wcx.hCursor = IntPtr.Zero;                    // predefined arrow 
        wcx.hbrBackground = IntPtr.Zero;                  // white background brush 
        wcx.lpszMenuName = "MainMenu";    // name of menu resource 
        wcx.lpszClassName = "EDIT";  // name of window class 
        wcx.hIconSm = IntPtr.Zero;

        // Register the window class. 
        return RegisterClassEx(ref wcx)!=0;
```

And here how I create the window

```
        int wndWidth = hwndRect.Right - hwndRect.Left;
        int wndHeight = hwndRect.Bottom - hwndRect.Top;
        Debug.WriteLine("Coord: " + hwndRect.Left.ToString() + "//" + hwndRect.Top.ToString() + "--" + wndWidth.ToString() + "//" + wndHeight.ToString());
        hwnd = User32.CreateWindowEx(
            User32.WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
            | User32.WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_TOPMOST
            | User32.WindowStylesEx.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW,
            wcx.lpszClassName, this.Name, User32.WindowStyles.WS_POPUP | User32.WindowStyles.WS_VISIBLE,
            hwndRect.Left, hwndRect.Top, wndWidth, wndHeight, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, wcx.hInstance, IntPtr.Zero
            );

        if (hwnd == null)
            return false;
```

RegisterClassEx returns a not zero value. So the registration may be succesful. So where is the cause? Without the execution of RegisterClassEx it works fine, but I like to set up somethings like referencing to WndProc Handler.
Any hints for me?

Comment: I think wcx.lpszClassName is case insensetive, and you have got mismatch with default "Edit" windows class, but I am not absolutely sure.

Comment: Tried it, but this is not the cause.

Comment: Your callback delegate is going to be GC'd out from under you. You need to extend its lifetime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"EDIT"` is the name of a predefined standard [window class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574.aspx) ([edit control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458.aspx)). You cannot use it to register your custom window class, because class names need to be unique within a process. Use a different class name instead.